# How to feed JSON to CASE CLASS directly using functional programming in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.0

```
{
    "cars": [{
        "amount": 120.00,
        "name": "Car1"
    }, {
        "amount": 245.00,
        "name": "Car2"
    }]
}
```

I am reading above JSON as following in my Controller

```
val body: JsObject = request.body.asInstanceOf[JsObject]
```

I am having following CASE CLASS

```
case class BIC(name: String, amount: Double)
```

I want to create List[BIC] objects by reading data from JSON [e.g. body] using Functional style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define two case classes for your model like this :

```
object Models {
  case class Bic(name : String, amount : Double)

  object Bic {
    implicit val BicFormat = Json.format[Bic]
  }

  case class Cars(bics : List[Bic])

  object Cars {
    implicit val CarsFormat = Json.format[Cars]    
  }

}
```

You're using the `Play Framework` so you can use the `JSON` library.

In  your controller, if you want to read the bics, you can do it like that :

```
def getCars = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[Cars] map { cars =>
      // treat your cars ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Play JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson).

Example:

```
case class Wrapper(cars: List[Bic])
case class BIC(name: String, amount: Double)
```

Then in your controller:

```
implicit val wrapperFormats = Json.format[Wrapper]
implicit val bICFormats     = Json.format[BIC]

def postCars(): Action[JsValue] = Action(json.parse) { implicit request =>
  request.body.validate[Wrapper] match {
    case JsSuccess(obj, _) => {
      //do something with obj.
    }
    case JsError(err) => {
      BadRequest(
        JsObject(
          "error" -> err.toString
        )
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that I am returning `Action[JsValue]` this is so [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) will run `success` when using AJAX.

I hope this helps,

Rhys

another reference:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators